# Stream over empty Collection, adding values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

What I would like to do is add values from 1 to 15 to the empty `HashSet`.

```
Set<Long> vipSeats = new HashSet<>();
```

Can I avoid using loop? Does Java have functional support for it e.g. stream ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
LongStream.rangeClosed(1, 15).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: `Set<Long> vipSeats = new HashSet<>(LongStream.rangeClosed(1, 15).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet()););` Since OP's is asking fot a `HashSet` and we have no guarantee concerning the type of `Set` returned by `Collectors.toSet()`

Comment: @YassinHajaj or `Collectors.toCollection(() -> vipSeats)`, to avoid creating two sets.

Comment: @Tunaki Even better !

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for an *expression* that evaluates to the set you want, then https://stackoverflow.com/a/36285091/3553087 is a fine answer.

If you want a *statement* that *adds* the numbers to an existing set, you can do:

```
LongStream.rangeClosed(1,15).forEach(vipSeats::add);
```

Comment: In that case you don’t need `.boxed()`…